# [Spark functions.udf(Object f, DataType dt) example]

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, udf

I need an example of using functions.udf(Object f, DataType dt) in Spark via Java, cant find it any where.
Is that for Column transforms? Can it apply for multiple columns transform?
If I want select col1 + col2 from myDataset, I must write my own udf too?
Hope you can help me with this in Java, big thank.